# write adt for stack operations

Tags: data-structures, stacks, abstract-data-types

Ok, I dont understand whats the difference between:
write code for stack operations and write adt for stack operations?

lets say the operation is push() and pop(). So what different code is to be written for adt?

Comment: Depends. What about completeness (isEmpty())? What about infrastructure (equals(), C++&co.: `new` and dispose())? (*begineer*?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is literal programming code (be it C/C++, Java, Python, etc.). We can agree the code will be completely different between languages. In addition, if you are implementing a stack, then you have modify your code depending on what underlying data structure you're using to store the data (c style arrays in C, ArrayLists in Java,  etc.).

ADT is a way to express the basic operations of the data type independently from the code (from any programming language). This leads to pseudocode.

For instance, a queue ADT might have the following functions: `enqueue`, `dequeue`, `front`. The `enqueue` function takes data and adds it to the back of the queue; the `dequeue` function removes data from the front of the queue and returns it; finally the `front` function simply returns the first data in the queue but does not remove it.

The above is the most basic queue ADT, but you could have other functions like `back`, `isEmpty`, or even something weird like `thirdPlaceInQueue`. It all depends on what your needs are. Be careful though, giving too much functionality may lead to a different ADT. For instance, if you gave a queue ADT the ability to add to the front and remove from the back, you would then have a deque ADT.